# Remove Duplicate Characters from SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Table Having 2 columns

```
Cust1    Cust2
A         B
C         A
A         C
C         D
B         A
D         C
```

We need to remove these duplicates and retain only one combination

So Output could be either

```
Cust1  Cust2
A       B
A       C
C       D
```

OR

```
Cust1   Cust 2
B       A
C        A
D       C
```

Comment: The needed output cannot be "or" - it must be deterministic.

Comment: It can be either of Two , the sequence of letters doesnt matter .
The final output should be that there should only be one combination of two letters

Comment: Yep, I think you need to decide which, but also seriously consider whether it's correct to remove data from your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting unique combinations:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(Cust1, Cust2) Cust1,
                GREATEST(Cust1, Cust2) Cust2
FROM source_table
```

Removing "duplicates" (assuming that there is no full duplicated rows, by both values and order - they won't be removed):

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM source_table t1
JOIN source_table t2 ON (t1.Cust1, t1.Cust2) = (t2.Cust2, t2.Cust1)
WHERE t1.Cust1 > t1.Cust2
```

Recommendation - create unique index by `(LEAST(Cust1, Cust2), GREATEST(Cust1, Cust2))`, it will forbid duplicates insertion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have pairs in both directions, then the simplest method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where cust1 < cust2;
```

If you want to modify the table, then:

```
delete t from t
    where cust1 > cust2;
```

Both of these can be modified to handle singletons, but there are no examples in your question.